# How to scrape data from a website that uses AJAX and JavaScript?

Tags: web-scraping

If a website uses AJAX and JavaScript to load content, it may be difficult to scrape data from the site. The data may be dynamically generated and stored in a JavaScript variable, making it inaccessible to a web scraper.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad and could have many different answers. Some tools that could be used to scrape data from a website that uses AJAX and JavaScript are Selenium, BeautifulSoup, and Scrapy.
This guide [here](https://www.scrapingdog.com/blog/how-scrape-using-scrapy-beat-captcha/) can help you understand how to use Scrapy to scrape AJAX and JavaScript.